# What is an heterogeneous object in java?

Tags: java, heterogeneous-array

When I am using any collection of generic type with `Object` class and I'm storing different objects in that collection in that situation.

Can I say that the collection contains heterogeneous objects or not?

Answer (score 17):

I've heard this term only once when *a heterogeneous object* referred to a *heterogeneous collection*, **a collection that can store objects of different types**.

A heterogeneous collection could be an `Object[]` array, or `List<Object>` list. We rarely use them (their declarations are too general - "a collection of everything" indicates design issues), but it's clear that it can contain instances of different types (e.g. `Integer` and `String`).

Answer (score 5):

"homo-" means same, "hetero-" means different.

In any case if a single Java array **can only store one type**, say, only numbers, or only strings then it is **homogeneous**.

If **multiple types** then **heterogeneous**. In the above case, since collection is of Object type and can hold any type

Let's take Javascript for understanding this better
eg. arrays are heterogeneous, because I can make an array that holds [5, "hello", new Object()], and in Java that's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that *heterogeneous objects* is a commonly used term that comes witha a clear and well defined meaning.

Thus *your* definition that says: objects of different classes are heterogeneous is fine.

( The problem arises later, when you assume that *other* people share that same understanding, and that is not necessarily true )